# Difference in using Task.Delay or Task.Run to start a task

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Both of the below result in the for loop running on it's own thread.  Neither of them are marked complete until the for loop completes.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task SomethingAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    Console.WriteLine("s11{0}  {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }
        );
    }
    static async Task SomethingAsync2()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("s22{0}  {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = SomethingAsync();
        var t2 = SomethingAsync2();

        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("m{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,t1.IsCompleted,t2.IsCompleted);
    }
}
```

Is there any functional difference?  (Apart from the obvious delay)

In the case of SomethingAsync2() Task.Delay was something I found by mistake.  Can the await call any method that returns a GetAwaiter?

Comment: Are you interested about Console Applications only, or about Windows Forms too?

Comment: In this case it is a Console App and a learning experiment. I had expected the Something2() method to end up back on the MainThread.  And I wanted to see how it blocked it, but surprisingly it ended up on a spare WorkerPool thread. But if I would get a different result in Forms then that would be good to understand.

Comment: Yes, if the process has a windows message queue (i.e., it's a GUI application), then the continuation after `await Task.Delay()` will be marshalled onto the UI thread that's processing the message queue (assuming that `Task.Delay()` was called from the UI thread). If the process does not have a message queue (e.g. a console app) or `Task.Delay()` was not called from the UI thread, then a thread from the thread pool will be used for the continuation.

Comment: `await Task.Run` is almost always an error. `Task.Run` - "please find some other thread to run this code, I've got other work to do". `await` - "well, I've got no useful work to do until that other work is done"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever What about if you want to call a long-running method in the background and update the UI when it returns? Using `await` with `Task.Run()` in that case avoids having to call `Control.Invoke()` to update the UI after the background task completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a console application doesn't have a synchronization context, the continuations will always be scheduled to a thread pool thread.

However, if a synchronization context is present (like in Windows Forms, WPF, UWP, etc.), continuations will be posted to the captured synchronization context.

See the [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).

By the way, `Task.Yield()` does what you're trying to do with `Task.Delay(1)` without involving a timer.